# How do I see what Blueprints I have unlocked?

Tags: starbound

I have found a whole bunch of blueprints, some that I was able to see in a crafting station. Is there any way to see a master list of blueprints I have unlocked away from the station that crafts it. For example I found a Lunar Console Blueprint very early on, but I have no idea where to make it, or what materials it needs. How can I find out in game?

Answer (score 1):

By blueprints I assume you mean the ones that unlock new furniture and the like.

Those are crafted in either the wooden workbench, or the industrial workbench.

[Starbounder page for Wooden Workbench,](http://starbounder.org/Wooden_Workbench) 
[and the one for the Industrial Workbench.](http://starbounder.org/Industrial_Workbench)

Comment: That's incorrect. The 3d printer makes objects which you *scanned*. All recipes from blueprints show up in the workbench.

Comment: @Philipp Ah frick, my bad. I've never paid attention to the blueprints, and I thought I remembered seeing them crafted there. I'll fix it!